# Getting the SHA-1 hash of a directory in Android Device using Busybox(Unix) and Local machine using Python dont return same value

Tags: android, python, sha1, monkeyrunner, busybox

I trying to do data validation on android,

I am calculating the sha-1 of my directory on the local machine as follows,

```
def getLocalFoldersChecksum(directory):
 directory = '/.../test-assets/testoswalk'
 SHAhash = hashlib.sha1()
 print SHAhash.hexdigest()
 if not os.path.exists (directory):
    return -1
 try:
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
        for names in files:
            filepath = os.path.join(root,names)
            try:
                f1 = open(filepath, 'rb')
            except:
                # You can't open the file for some reason
                f1.close()
                continue     
            SHAhash.update(hashlib.sha1(f1.read()).hexdigest())
            f1.close()
 except:
    return -1
 return SHAhash.hexdigest()
```

and I'am getting the Sha-1 of the directory on the Android Device(using Busybox) as follows,

```
BUSY_BOX = "/data/local/tmp/busybox"
def getDeviceFoldersChecksum(directory):
   cmd = BUSY_BOX + ' find /mnt/sdcard/testoswalk -type f -exec ' + BUSY_BOX + 
        ' sha1sum {} \; | ' + BUSY_BOX + ' sort  | ' + BUSY_BOX + ' sha1sum '
   checksum = device.shell(cmd)
   return checksum
```

But the values returned by these two functions, dont match.

I tried similarly to check the Sha-1 of files in Android and Local machine and that works perfectly,

```
def getFilesChecksum():
   ck1 = hashlib.sha1(open('/.../test-assets/testoswalk/abc.xml').read()).hexdigest()
   cmd = BUSY_BOX + ' sha1sum /mnt/sdcard/testoswalk/abc.xml'
   ck2 = device.shell(cmd)  
   ck2 = ck2.split(' ')[0]
   if(ck1 == ck2):
       return True
   return False
```

I am sure the issue is with the way the files are ordered in the directory and consumed by Sha-1, I have tried various permutation but with no luck. Thanks for the help.

---

Resolution is as follows,

Compute the SHA-1 on android device using the adb shell as follows,

```
$ rm -f SHA1SUMS
$ /data/local/tmp/busybox find /mnt/sdcard/testoswalk -type f -print0 | /data/local/tmp/busybox xargs -0  /data/local/tmp/busybox sha1sum >> SHA1SUMS 
$ /data/local/tmp/busybox cut -c-40 SHA1SUMS | /data/local/tmp/busybox sha1sum
```

And compute the SHA-1 on local machine using python as follows

```
def getLocalFoldersChecksum(directory):
 directory = '/.../test'
 SHAhash = hashlib.sha1()
 print SHAhash.hexdigest()
 try:
    f = open('/.../test/SHA1SUMS','w')  
 except:
    return -1
 if not os.path.exists (directory):
    return -1
 try:
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
        for names in files:
            filepath = os.path.join(root,names)
            try:
                f1 = open(filepath, 'rb')
            except:
                # You can't open the file for some reason
                f1.close()
                continue     
            f.write(hashlib.sha1(f1.read()).hexdigest())
            f.write('\n')
            f1.close()
 except:
    return -1

 f.close()
 f = open('/.../test/SHA1SUMS','rb')
 t = hashlib.sha1(f.read()).hexdigest()
 f.close()
 return t
```

Answer (score 0):

First, all your problems will go away if you just keep the filenames in the SHA1 list you generate on the device. Another solution is to ensure the same order by, for example, running the SHA1 hashes through a sort function before combining them into a single one.

Alternatively, use a commutative function to combine the list of SHA1 hashes, so that the ordering doesn't matter.